# Print path to base in template override

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

I am doing a template override with my template.php, and I need to print the path to the base of my site.

Currently I have this:

```
$output = '<div id="my-basket-text"><a href="/cart">My Basket</a></div>' . '<div id="my-basket-no-items">' . $item_count . '</div>';
```

The link created is:

```
<a href="/cart">My Basket </a>
```

I understand why this is happening and why this link doesn't work.

If I was adding code to a tpl file, I would use PHP to print the path to the base of my site first. However using the same code in my `template.php` doesn't work; the code is shown as text on the page.

How can I get around this? Am I trying to do it in the right way?

NOTE - The code $item_count works fine as it is, but when I tried to use it to add a class to a div it also just printed the text: `'' . $item_count . ''`.

This makes me wonder if I am using the correct code for the base path, but applying it wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use drupal's link function **[l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7)**. Check this page for the url's options available.

So, your link should be

```
$output = l('My Basket', 'cart');
```

If you use that for your links, Drupal will handle the base path for you.

Comment: I had to remove the ; so I got it working with: $output = '<div id="my-basket-text">' . l('My Basket', 'cart') . '</div>' . '<div id="my-basket-no-items">' . $item_count . '</div>';   Thanks